# Avoid faux bold and italic styles when using webfonts over fonts.com

Tags: webfonts, webfont-loader

I'm using the webfont service of fonts.com to include webfonts to my site. However, the publishing options of this service are not sufficient enough in my case. What I want is to be able to declare the font-weight and font-style for every font that is loaded. This way, I avoid getting faux bold or italic styles if for some reason the webfont can't be loaded. You can find more on this topic here: http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/how-use-font-face-avoid-faux-italic-and-bold-browser-styles

I then stumbled upon the [Google Webfont Loader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader) and tried to use it to solve my problem. However, I can't figure out if and how I'm able to set font-weight and font-style for a loaded font.com webfont. Any ideas?

PS: I'm aware that there is a self-hosting option at fonts.com which would easily solve the problem, but that's a pricey option :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to fix fonts.com @font-face declarations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824925/is-there-any-way-to-fix-fonts-com-font-face-declarations)